# Get file paths from a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory-structure

I am looking to get all the file paths from my images folder.

The file path in relation to my root is image/picture.jpg

I have seen the example of

```
foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(@"\image\"))
```

But this looks for a direct path, I am unsure as to how to use this code.

Can anyone suggest what I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) as so:

```
foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath( "~/image")))
{

}
```

`Server.MapPath` returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server.